# Dynamically update tag value when dateinput changes

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, reactive

Is it possible to update a tag value when dateInput is changed by a user?
Maybe something like force, eventReactive, reactivevalue or stop lazy evaluation?

```
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


data <- data.frame(
  date=seq.Date(from=dmy("1/1/2022"),to=dmy("31/1/2022"),by="day"),
  y=round(rnorm(n=31,mean=0,sd=2),2)
)

date_selected <- ""

# fn_lookup(date_in="")
fn_lookup <- function(date_in){
  
  if(length(date_in)>0){
    y=(data %>% filter(date==dmy(date_in)))$y
  }else{
    y=""
  }
  return(y)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(12,actionButton(inputId="edit_table",label="edit",icon=icon("edit")))
    ),
  fluidRow(
    br(),
    br(),
    column(12,DT::dataTableOutput('table')))
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(data)
  
  observeEvent(input$edit_table,{
    
    date_selected <- eventReactive(input$ad1, {     input$ad1  })
    
    showModal(modalDialog(
      tagList(
        div(style="display:inline-block;",
            dateInput(inputId="ad1",label="Date",value="2022-1-15",format="dd/mm/yyyy")
        ),
        div(style="display:inline-block;",
            tags$label("value static"),
            tags$input(id = "ad2", type = "text", class="form-control",value = fn_lookup("15/1/2022"))
        ),
        div(style="display:inline-block;",
            tags$label("value dynamic"),
            #dynamically update this tag value when the date input changes
            tags$input(id = "ad3", type = "text", class="form-control",value = fn_lookup(input$ad1))
        ),
        div(style="display:inline-block;",
            tags$label("value dynamic 2"),
            #dynamically update this tag value when the date input changes
            # tags$input(id = "ad3", type = "text", class="form-control",value = fn_lookup(date_selected))
        )
      ),
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Cancel"),
        actionButton(inputId="check", "Check",icon=icon("check"))
      ),
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```